# Convert from Picasso to Glide

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

I try to use Glide library in my application instead using Picasso, but in my application i implement specific request handler like this

```
  public static final String SCHEME = "attachment";
  public static final String DOCUMENT_ID_PARAM = "document_id";
  public static final String ATTACHMENT_NAME_PARAM = "attachment_name";

  private final Context mContext;

  public PicassoAttacHandler(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean canHandleRequest(Request data) {
    return data != null && data.uri != null && SCHEME.equals(data.uri.getScheme());
  }

  @Override
  public Result load(Request request, int networkPolicy) throws IOException {
    if (request != null && request.uri != null) {
      final String documentId = request.uri.getQueryParameter(DOCUMENT_ID_PARAM);
      final String attachmentName = request.uri.getQueryParameter(ATTACHMENT_NAME_PARAM);
      final InputStream attachmentStream = Attachment.getAttachmentAsStream(Database.getInstance(mContext), attachmentName, documentId);
      if (attachmentStream != null) {
        return new Result(attachmentStream, Picasso.LoadedFrom.DISK);
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

How can i achieve this using Glide ? i search to find any guide to make this but not found anything ? any help ? or any guide, tutorial any examples?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a look at this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani ok fine I know that, so what wrong in my question ? i just ask for instruction because i don't found anything to help me